# jquery обращение к элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery как обратиться к элементу с `id="xfield[price]"`
Делаю вот так ничего не происходит

```
$(function() {
    alert($("#xfield[price]").val());
});
```

Comment: jQuery подключен? или что?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$(function() {
    alert($("#xfield\\[price\\]").val());
});
```

### UPDATE

Я в таких случаях использую функцию для escaping.

```
function escapeSelector(selector) {
    if (!selector) return false;
    var specials = [
      '#', '&', '~', '=', '>', 
      "'", ':', '"', '!', ';', ','
    ];
    var regexSpecials = [
      '.', '*', '+', '|', '[', ']', '(', ')', '/', '^', '$'
    ];
    var sRE = new RegExp(
      '(' + specials.join('|') + '|\\' + regexSpecials.join('|\\') + ')', 'g'
    );

    return selector.replace(sRE, '\\$1');
}
```

В Вашем варианте это должно работать вот так:

```
$(function() {
    alert($("#" + escapeSelector("xfield[price]")).val());
});
```

Попробуйте. Сработает - дарю ;)

### UPDATE 2

@Igor также предоставил код, работающий на чистом javascript

```
alert(document.getElementById("xfield\[price\]").value);
```

Comment: Не получается((9

Comment: need double escaping `$("#xfield\\[price\\]")`